# solving a Euler implicite equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation like this: $$ŷ(t_{n}+1) = ŷ(t_{n}) + h \beta ŷ(t_{n+1})[1-\frac{ŷ(t_{n+1})}{N}]$$ which is a Euler implicite function.
What I want to do is to find $ŷ(t_{n}+1)$ but I don't know how to do that? I have already the answer which is $$y(t_{n}+1) = \frac{-1+h \beta \sqrt{(-1+h \beta)^2 + 4 \frac{h \beta}{N} ŷ(t_{n})}}{\frac{2h \beta }{N}} $$ but I want to know how to get to this answer.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You make the effort to write `\hat y(t_{n}+1)`. Are you sure that this is correct? In the implicit Euler method I would expect to also have `\hat y(t_{n+1})` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are solving 
$$
z=y+az(1-z),~~z=\hat y_{n+1}/N, ~ y=\hat y_n/N,~ a=h\beta,
$$
which is a quadratic equation in $z$, for the solution closest to $y$. Now just apply the solution formula
$$
z=y+az-az^2\\
(az+\tfrac12(1-a))^2=\tfrac14(1-a)^2+ay\\
z=\frac{a-1+\sqrt{(1-a)^2+4ay}}{2a}
=\frac{2y}{1-a+\sqrt{(1-a)^2+4ay}}.
$$